# "No Such Table: TableName" Error in the Android

Tags: android, sqlite, jquery-mobile, cordova

I am developing application in the Eclipse using jquery Mobile and Phonegap
Using sqlite for Database creation.
The sqlite shows the following exception **"No Such Table:Table Name"**
How to correct this? Please help me.

---

Thanks for the reply....
To create a table following code is used:

```
var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE  IF NOT EXISTS Contact (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, firstName TEXT, lastName TEXT, phone TEXT)";
```

Function to insert the records:

```
function insertRecord() {

     var d=document.getElementById('firstName');
     var ds= document.getElementById('lastName');  
     var dsq=document.getElementById('phone');

     db.transaction(function(tx) {
              tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [d.value, ds.value, dsq.value], loadAndReset, onError);            
         });
}
```

Comment: Lol my car is not working, can you tell me whats wrong and how to correct this?

Comment: To me, it looks very much like you you are trying to insert stuff into a table with the name "Table Name". Go check if your insertStatement is correct.

Answer (score 0):

without any code, i'd say that the SQLite Request is not correct. Can you just post the part of your code where you do the request ?